# Update multiple rows by the trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I use below trigger for updating rows, if `fld_IsUpdated` set true.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateFieldDate_GroupChat] ON [dbo].[tbl_GroupChat]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     IF
     (
         SELECT i.fld_IsUpdated
         FROM inserted i
     ) = 1
         BEGIN
             DECLARE @now BIGINT= (CONVERT([BIGINT], replace(replace(replace(CONVERT([VARCHAR](19), GETDATE(), (121)), ':', ''), '-', ''), ' ', ''), (0)));
             UPDATE tbl_GroupChat
               SET 
                   tbl_GroupChat.fld_ModifiedAt = @now
             WHERE tbl_GroupChat.fld_Id =
             (
                 SELECT i.fld_Id
                 FROM inserted i
             );
     END;
```

When I execute an update query like `UPDATE tbl_GroupChat SET fld_IsUpdated = 1;`, SSMS shows below error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateFieldDate_GroupChat, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I test many structures of triggers but all of them has the same error, for example with below code, I don't declare variable:

```
 tbl_GroupChat.fld_ModifiedAt = (CONVERT([BIGINT], replace(replace(replace(CONVERT([VARCHAR](19), GETDATE(), (121)), ':', ''), '-', ''), ' ', ''), (0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here:

```
IF
     (
         SELECT i.fld_IsUpdated
         FROM inserted i
     ) = 1
```

you compare fld_IsUpdated to 1. However, the `inserted` table has multiple rows, and thus the `select` is an entire table. A table cannot be compared to a single value.

Try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateFieldDate_GroupChat] ON [dbo].[tbl_GroupChat]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @now BIGINT= (CONVERT([BIGINT], replace(replace(replace(CONVERT([VARCHAR](19), GETDATE(), (121)), ':', ''), '-', ''), ' ', ''), (0)));

        UPDATE t 
        SET tbl_GroupChat.fld_ModifiedAt = @now
        FROM tbl_GroupChat as t
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.fld_Id=i.fld_Id
        WHERE i.fld_IsUpdated=1
     END;
```

Comment: How to check if the fld_IsUpdated update to true or not? because I want to fire the trigger if field set to true.